# Updating a model in the backend in qt

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt.
I have the following situation.
Can someone suggest me how to tackle it.Thanks
I have a custom made model which i should populate in the backend.ie when the program starts there is no guarantee there will be elements in the model.But these elements may be added later in the backend.So if i add a new element in the data structure in the model how do i let the view know the change.And this is an insertion and not a change in the data.

Also if i want the view i display to be sorted how should i notify the view

Comment: the official examples dont seem to be enough for you? Hint: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-masterdetail.html

Answer (score 0):

To update any connected views of an insertion, call `beginInsertRows(const QModelIndex& parent, int first, int last)` before you modify the model, and `endInsertRows()` after.  Read the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows).

To sort views you need to use a `QAbstractProxyModel`, it is highly configurable so read the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractproxymodel.html) before asking more specific questions about it.

Comment: Thanks.I just have one doubt.In docs for insertRows() it says that we can provide custom API for inserting rows with beginInsertRows and endInsertRows.So if we insert in the datastructure in model within these 2 signals will the change be reflected in the view??

Comment: Yes. You can also use `dataChanged` signal.

Comment: @user2454413 They are methods, not signals - but they emit the appropriate signals on your behalf.